# Java paint() method overflow

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paint

Could someone explain to me why I need to put the `repaint()` method in this code ?
If I don't do it I get a `stackoverflow` error

```
private class GamePanel extends JPanel
{
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        onPaint(g);
    }
 }


protected void onPaint(Graphics g)
{
    frameRate.calculate();
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.drawString(frameRate.getFrameRate(),30,30);
    repaint();
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

> If i dont do it i get a stackoverflow error

Based on the code provided we can't tell you why you get a stack overflow. The problem is probably in your one of your methods related to the `frameRate` object.

Don't invoke `repaint()` from a painting method, this will cause an infinite painting loop.

If you are trying to do animation of some kind then you should be using a `Swing Timer` to schedule the animation and when the `Timer` fires you invoke `repaint()`.

Also, don't override paint(...). Custom painting is done by overriding `paintComponent(...)`.

Comment: Just delete your comments.